# iBeacon detection not consistent

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, ibeacon

When I'm testing my iBeacon enabled iOS application for different scenarios with iOS 9, I've found that it doesn't discover the iBeacon for a quite a while after I toggle on Bluetooth.

Scenario is as follows,
I kill my application, turn Bluetooth off and then lock the phone. Then I wake the phone via power button and in the lock screen I turn on Bluetooth via the Control Center and wait till the iBeacon monitoring starts.

In the device log I've noticed that the iBeacon monitoring and app ranging has not started even after several attempts.

This scenario fails more often than not in an iPhone 5 which is updated to iOS 9.0.2 and recently I've noticed that this is there in iOS 8.4 device as well.

Any sort of help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try settings allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true and also pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false, this should help resolve your issues.

Comment: What specifically do you see in the log that suggests monitoring is not started?

Comment: @davidgyoung I have debug logs in the ranging and they are not showing. Once it worked after about 20 mins, I continuously made the phone wake when it goes to sleep automatically inspecting the logs.
I'm wondering if this is a normal behavior as I've read in one of your comments ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/26498144 )

Comment: OK, so to be clear you are saying that ranging also does not work in this scenario.  In the question, you only mentioned monitoring.  You may wish to modify your question to make that clear.

Comment: We've been working with iBeacons (estimote) and Wallet. Lastly on iOS 9 it's not working. On iOS 8 versions it was working fine.